# Can't select cms page/blog or product/category widget

Tags: backend, widgets, cms-block, widget, widget-instance

I realy hope you can help me with this...

I have installed a brand new Magento at GoDaddy. Everything but Widgets works fine...

[image]
[image]

The button that should appear in Plugin Detail are simply missing.

No matters which browser i'm using. The only way I can made this button shows up was importing a magento's instalation (1.8.1.1) from another server.

I've tryed with CE 1.9.2.2 and CE 1.9.1.0, both without success

Nothing in console.

What do you guys think? Have you ever seen this problem before?

`system.log`

```
2015-11-21T00:04:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
[5] /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/index.php:83
</pre>
```

`exception.log`

```
2015-11-22T16:00:50+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Tipo de bloco inválido: Mage_Dynamicslideshow_Block_List' in /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Tipo de bloco i...')
#1 /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('dynamicslidesho...', Array)
#2 /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('dynamicslidesho...', 'dynamicslidesho...')
#3 /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('dynamicslidesho...', 'dynamicslidesho...')
#4 /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#9 /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#10 /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /home/myhappyface/public_html/loja/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Comment: how did you install the site? or was it already pre installed with goDaddy?

Comment: I've tryed with automatic installation tool (Installatron) first. After it I've tryed to upload all the content downloaded from magento's site

Comment: are you able to see if there is anything in the `system.log` or `exception.log` ?

Comment: I don't think this exeption is related to this problem, couse it calls template block. I already have tested without any template instaled. I've tested with and without sample data too...

Comment: Do you have any JS errors on the page in question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After another test batery I figure out the problem was in theme.

I've been testing with default theme, but my custom theme's files aleready was in the server.

Thanks for yout good will!